# Rails: Show search results without refreshing tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a search `form_tag` inside a `bootstrap tab` and I would like to show the results without refreshing the page and inside the `tab`.

I added the `remote: true` to the `form_tag` along with the `respond_to do |format|` to the search action inside the controller, but when I submit the search the page still reloads.

this is the setup I have thus far?

search.html.errb

```
<div class="container">
<div id="tabs">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="prodTabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#nsearch">Search</a></li>
    <li><a href="#other">Other</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="search">

      <%= render 'pages/search' %>

      <% if params[:search].present? %>
          <% if @items.blank? %>

              <div class="centerList">
                <p>No results found</p>
              </div>

          <% else %>

              <h5> Result:</h5>
              <% @items.each do |item|%>

                 <% unless item.attachments.blank? %>
                 <%= image_tag item.attachments.first&.url(:mini) %>
                            <% end %>

                  <%= link_to item.title, items_show_path(item) %></h4>
                  <strong>Price: </strong><%= number_to_currency item.price %>


<script>
  $('#tabs').on('click','.tablink,#prodTabs a',function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var url = $(this).attr("data-url");

      if (typeof url !== "undefined") {
          var pane = $(this), href = this.hash;

          // ajax load from data-url
          $(href).load(url,function(result){
              pane.tab('show');
          });
      } else {
          $(this).tab('show');
      }
  });
```

_search.html.erb

```
<%= form_tag search_items_path, remote: true, :method => "get" do %>
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], autofocus: true,
                   class: "search-query search_size",
                   placeholder: "Enter keyword to search" %>
<%= submit_tag "Search", name: nil, :style => "display: none;" %>
<%end%>
```

controller action:

```
def search
  if params[:search]
    @items = Item.search(params[:search]).order("created_at DESC")

     respond_to do |format|
      format.js
      format.html
     end
  end
end
```

Any ideas how to fix this issue?

Comment: Is everything working in the controller as it should?
Do you have a valid `@items` before `respond_to do ...`? If, you need to append the data to your erb. Right now you're just showing the tab, but the data is not being appended.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Peter Andersen! Yes everything is working as it should, I'm getting a valid `@items` and thus the results from my search are showing up, I just don't won it to refresh the page. Also, I have a `search.js.erb` with this inside `$("#items").innerHTML += "<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'search')) %>"`

Comment: Do you have any error on rails console and on browser console?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with innerHTML on jquery object. You should use append instead of innerHTML. Open console and check you might be getting error of innerHTML is not a function. And put `return false` at the end of  `$('#tabs').on('click','.tablink,#prodTabs a',function (e) {` code.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Manishh! I changes `innerHTML` to this `$("#items").append("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'search_results', locals: { items: @items } ) %>");` but still the page reloads upon the search!

Comment: I'm not getting any error inside the browser inspector and the terminal as well.... weird! I also added the `return false`

Answer (score 0):

You need to append the data to your view, but something is wrong in your jQuery.

So, let's try the Rails way.

When you use

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.js 
end
```

You have the `search.js.erb` to handle your variables in the corresponding view folder `views/controller_name/search.js.erb`

If you create that file and do the same thing as you wrote before:

*By the way - you can use the shortcut: `<%=j(...) %>` instead of `<%= escape_javascript(..) %>` if you want to*

```
$("#items").append("<%=j(render partial: 'search_results', locals: { items: @items } ) %>");
// show something
```

You can remove your jQuery. Rails knows that you want to submit the data to the corresponding url `search_term_path` when you hit 'Search'.

I think it will work, and you will save some code.

But you need to be sure that your search_terms_path is set up properly, or else the `form_tag` will not 'hit' the controller action.

I would recommend reading [Working with javascript in Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html) for further info.

And remember to check that your partial file: ´_search_result.html.erb´ is without errors.

Good luck!